# Using PDF metadata to identity the files using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

Scenario - I have statements of  10 banks in pdf files.  They are all in different formats. Each of these files has a corresponding parser to extract the data . Now we supply the files to the parser according to the file name.

But the now the source is not supplying the proper filenames. Hence we were not able to route the file to the corresponding parser.

My doubts,

1. Does every pdf file has metadata or is it optional?
2. Can i use the metadata to distinguish the PDF files to route the files to 
   corresponding parser.
3. I used the following code to extract the metadata from my files and it looks very confusing.

   http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter12&ex=MetadataXmp
   5]

What is the best way to automate this process.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pdf metadata are optional

Answer (score 0):

In ISO 32000-1, two different types of metadata are allowed:

- Metadata in an info dictionary,
- An XMP metadata stream.

The Info dictionary was deprecated in ISO 32000-2.

The example you refer to is an XMP example. XMP stands for the eXtensible Metadata Platform. It's metadata that is stored as plain text inside a binary file in XML format. XMP can be used in PDF, JPG, PNG,... It is not limited to PDF; you can also find XMP metadata in other types of files.

Moreover XMP is optional. The first version of the XMP specification was published in 2004 (developed in 2001 by Adobe), whereas the first PDF specification was published in 1993. It goes without saying that many PDF file lack metadata in the XMP format.

If you want to detect if a file is a PDF file, you can look at the first 7 bytes. If the first 7 bytes match `%PDF-1.`, then you have a PDF file that probably follows ISO 32000-1 (2008). If the first 7 match `%PDF-2.`, then you have a PDF file that claims to be compliant with ISO 32000-2 (2017).